# Does oracle SAMPLE work with where filter?

Tags: oracle

We are usign ORACLE and need to get a random row from a table, satisfying a particular condition. I searched and and found that sample might be useful in this case. 
However, as I understand Sample returns a random subset of a specified size of the entire table. 
So in our case, since we need rows that match a particular WHERE condition, it is possible that the query might not return any rows, even if the table contains rows for that filter.

SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column FROM table SAMPLE(10) WHERE COLUMN='abc' )
WHERE rownum = 1

In the above query, if the 10% sample set does not contain any row with column 'abc' it will return empty result (even though the 90% might contain such rows)

Any suggestions to correct this behavior?

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16024737/409172).  `SAMPLE` doesn't always work as expected.  You'll probably want to use the `rownumber` method in Alex's answer, to ensure that you always get a random row.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem here... The column='abc' may be 7%, not 10. This is why you get null in result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT column FROM table WHERE COLUMN='abc')
SELECT column FROM data SAMPLE(10) 
WHERE rownum = 1
```